# Error obfuscating .jar used by a project library

Tags: android, obfuscation

Here on the app I'm currently developing I have two projects, A and B. The project B is marked as a Library that is used by A. I had some issues when obfuscating this (the "already added" error) but I have it already figured out. The thing is that now I'm importing the google android-support-v4.jar, and it is used on both A and B projects, so I had to add android-support-v4.jar to both A and B. Now everytime I try to export a signed application I get the good old "davlik error 1".

Any Ideas?

Thank you.